# Understanding the availability of JQuery Plugin Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I am writing a JQuery plugin and all is well so far...Though I have a question that I can not seem to find an answer too.

First, lets say this is the plugin skeleton

```
(function ($) {

 var outterFunction = function () {};

     $.fn.cssLive = function (getTargets, getStyles) {
         /// Some Stuff
         var innerFunction = function () {};
     }

}(jQuery));
```

My Questions are as follows...

1. Are either `innerFunction` or `outterFunction` available globally?
2. Should `outterFunction` be declared within `$.fn.cssLive` if I do not need it to be available globally?
3. Lastly, if `outterFunction` requires a variable to be set by a developer using my plugin, would I be extending `$.fn.cssLive`? and if so, how?

My plugin is quite large as of now and it seems most all of my functions are in the realm of the `outterFunction`, turns out I am only using the `$.fn.cssLive` to get two parameters. Is this standard or do most plugins have all the functions inside of the main plugin function.

I will be here to answer any questions or go back and forth if needed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. whether those methods will be available globally

Ans: no, they won't be because they are declared in a local scope

Comment: 3. can you explain what do you mean by *would I be extending $.fn.cssLive*?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I mean using something like `var opts = $.extend( {}, $.fn.cssLive.fontOptions, options );`

Comment: in that case you need to pass the opts object or the desired property as a parameter to `outterFunction`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Can you expound on your comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) no
2) it depends what it does, but probably to introduce a tighter scope
3) no it would not be extending it, but I'm not sure if that is what you're asking

Comment: Ok, so on question 3, is there an elegant way for a user to declare an object that my plugin needs besides using just `myObj = { key : "value" }`

Comment: There are many ways to create a javascript object, I wouldn't really say one way is more elegant than another. The EC5 methods may be more intuitive, but it often comes down to preference.  Here's the reference I use for 5: http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/